# Wedding website RSVP database

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

I am creating a wedding website for my brother, and one of his requirements in that the user can go onto a page titled 'RSVP'.

Once on the 'RSVP' page, the user will be presented with a simple form:

```
First Name | Surname
Email | Phone Number
Attending the Wedding? (drop down box with options yes | no)
```

Once the user clicks submit it will do one of two things.

If the user select `'no'` to the option `'Attending the Wedding?'`, then send the information to the database, display it in a table and send an email to my brother telling him that this person has filled out the form and that they will not be coming to the wedding.

However, if the user clicks `'yes'` to the option `'Attending the Wedding?'` than they will be asked further questions about where they are staying etc. Upon submitting that information the details will need to be stored in the database, represented in a `table` and sent to my brother via email informing him that this person in coming and there answers to the other questions.

I am going to be using PHP and MySQL for this project, MySQL for the database queries and other database work and PHP for the Form processing etc`.

Could anyone provide me with a start to finish step by step guide as to how they would tackle this so my brother can have this fantastic aspect to his wedding website.

My thoughts so far are:

1. Create HTML table/form
   (I'm confident with this, will be able to make drop down box and form etc.)
2. If user selection = no, store in database, display in table, email brother. 
   (Will be able to do if function but not able to store it in the database and email brother results. Will be able to display results in table.)
3. If user selection = yes, ask more questions about where they are staying, upon submission of there answers to the second round of questions, store in database, display in table, email brother. 
   (Will be able to do `if` function and display the second round of questions but not able to store it in the database and email brother results. Will be able to display results in table.)

If I'm missing anything please inform me, i.e. any steps, vital information I have left out etc.

So what I am looking for is, *your* step by step approach to this, and some links, material that would help me with the parts I identified I would need some help on, i.e. storing the users responses in the database and email the results to my brother.

***P.S., I'm not looking for people to code this for me, I'm just looking for peoples ideas on how they would approach this***.

Comment: Why didn't you just write: Can someone code this for me?

Comment: Im not looking for someone to code this for me just a little help and how they would approach this.

Comment: From a user-interface perspective, consider using radio buttons instead for the Yes/No. I find drop-downs for 2 lousy little options to be infuriating.

Comment: @Michael-O - Instead of vote trolling look at more constructive answers received and try to emulate this in the hope you may actually help me.

Comment: @Marc B, Ahh ok, that sounds like a sensible option, thanks alot

Comment: Ryan, I wouldn't waste so much effort for a one-time event/app. I'd rather set up a simple CMS for this.

Comment: @Michael-O could you recommend me a good CMS for this?

Comment: Well, though there are [tens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP) of them, [Joomla!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla!) is a good point to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple framework like CakePHP http://cakephp.org/ helps you set up everything fast an easy. Their cookbook in the learn section has a couple of tutorials to get you started and is pretty well documented.

Also seems you're fairly new to web dev so maybe a stroll through http://www.w3schools.com/ tutorials might also give you a good idea about how you can build this.

Comment: ahh right, had that mentioned by a friend, but now a member of the stack community recommends it Ill look into it more. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

your thoughts so far are correct. As you seem to be new to PHP and web development in general, I suggest to have a look at the [Quickstart Tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) of the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), which will teach you everything you need to know (besides mailing, which is handled by [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html)).

30 Minutes will get you started with storing and retrieving data from and to the database, some nice patterns and how to use the Zend Documentation and Reference pages, so everything you need to know.

Comment: Cool, will have a look at that. cheers

Comment: You're welcome - I've created webpage for a friend's wedding, too, with help of the Zend Framework and we had the complete organisation on it, so I know that it's very fast and easy to tackle. Best wishes from StackOverflow. ;)

Comment: Cheers, Im actually on it now, seems like a good place to start learning.